# MySQL: How do I count instances of an object and then display that which has the most instances of said object?

Tags: mysql

My Goal: Display the user who has submitted the most recipes.

Suppose I have a table called Recipe with the following attributes:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `myDB`.`Recipe`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
recipeName
servingSize
submittedBy
userRating
```

submittedBy references another table called User which lists several usernames.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT submittedBy
FROM Recipe
WHERE COUNT(submittedBy) = 
(
    SELECT 
    /*I am not quite sure how to go on from here*/
);
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following query:

```
SELECT submittedBy, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM Recipe
GROUP BY submittedBy
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @user3466896 I am sorry but I don't understand your comment. My query retrieves one line with two fields, submittedBy and count. The first stores the user with more recipes and the second the number of recipes he submitted